# idangero Swiper responsize break points not working

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, responsive, swiper.js

Hi I'm using iDangero Swiper on a website I'm doing and for some reason I cant get the responsive break points to work. below is the js I'm using.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.s1', {
 slidesPerView: 5,
 slidesPerColumn: 2,
 spaceBetween: 30,
 nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
 prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
 breakpoints: {
  1024: {
   slidesPerView: 5,
   spaceBetween: 30
  },
  768: {
   slidesPerView: 1,
   spaceBetween: 10
  },
  640: {
   slidesPerView: 1,
   spaceBetween: 10
 },
 320: {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10
 }
},
});
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong

Comment: Facing same issue. Can't find any solution even after exploring documentation.

Comment: these breakpoints worked fine check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175356/13358761)

Comment: these breakpoints work fine [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175356/13358761)

Answer (score 24):

Currently the docs have things confusingly backwards, which is why I think many people are having issues (especially those working with sass media statements and/or ionic for example).

[image]

The issue is the crocodile symbols. They're the wrong way around. They should read '*// when window width is <=320px*'. Hence the method is to work backwards from the default options (eg `slidesPerView`, `spaceBetween` etc).

For example:

```
{
  ...
  slidesPerView: 5,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  breakpoints: {
    ...
    960: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 8
    },
    720: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 6
    },
    540: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 4
    },
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 2
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

So we start with a default `slidesPerView` of 5 and `spaceBetween` of 10px, which is suitable for your average laptop/desktop. For screen sizes less than or equal  to (<=) 960px, we set `slidesPerView` to 4 and `spaceBetween` to 8px. Then for screen sizes less than or equal to 720px, we set `slidesPerView` to 3 and `spaceBetween` to 8px. And so on.

Because things are mistakenly backwards, we work backwards, which ironically turns out to be more intuitive.

Comment: That's true. Experienced the same issue and your comment helped me make things work. In the documentation the media queries should say *window width is <= 640px* in order to work. I will try to reach out to @nolimits4web who is the creator of Swiper.

Comment: In Swiper 5.3.0 it works just like in documentation

Comment: got the same error, create a PR to Swiper doc repo to fix https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper-website/pull/54

Comment: Worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and removing the following lines solved the problem for me:

```
slidesPerView: 5,
slidesPerColumn: 2,
spaceBetween: 30,
```

It turns out they override the breakpoints values.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all answered  - check this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

as is. Once this solved the issue for me. (I used to have this: 
**`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`>** and Siwper's breakpoints didn't work. Update to the code above had solved the problem.)

Comment: Breakpoints did almost work for me without specifying minimum- and maximum-scale, yet the breakpoints were slightly off (e.g. 769px happened at 756px). Can't understand why, but using this meta tag did solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

in my case none of the solutions worked but the following worked...

```
  // Swiper
  const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    // slidesPerView: 6
    centeredSlides: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    breakpoints: {
      320: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 50,
      },
      375: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 0,
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 0,
      },
    },
  });
```

Larger than 1024 screens was taking 2 slides from 320 breakpoint, i removed my default slidesPerView from 1st config level to put it in breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but years later I'm having a similar issue with the breakpoints. What worked for me was to **repeat the 'slidesPerView' declaration in each breakpoint.** For some reason if i left that property out of a breakpoint object, the 'slidesPerView' property would revert back to the first declaration, which was always '1' slide. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In Swiper 5.3.0 it works just like in [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/).

You might need to update your configuration if you are upgrading from 4.x like I did.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Default parameters
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was the declaration was inside ready() method

$(document).ready(function() {

});

I moved it outside,
I hope this help some have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and removing the last comma before the closure parenthesis.

```
breakpoints: {
 530: {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 5
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Removing slidesPerView in the general swiper configuration worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, but this could have been done in a comment on the correct answer :)

Comment: Oh you are right  mb

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this is set with min-media queries, which is not immediate in the documentation.

Here's a working example:

```
new Swiper(.swiper, {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    breakpoints: {
       1000: {
         slidesPerView: 2,
       },
       1400: {
         slidesPerView: 3,
       },
     },
})
```

So in this example on smaller screens we would have one slide per screen, on 1000px it will be two and then 3 from 1400px onwards.

Answer (score -3):

may be trying removing the ',' after the last parenthesis.

```
...    
320: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 10
     }
    }
    });
```