# Swiper spaceBetween doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, slider, gallery, swiper.js

I'am trying to use `slidesPerView: 'auto'` with `spaceBetween: 20` property, but [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/) shows only one slide per view.

I want to show next slide right after the first one even if it will be cutted by the document width.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     //initialize swiper when document ready
     var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        // Optional parameters
        loop: false,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        navigation: {
           prevEl: '.slider .prev-btn',
           nextEl: '.slider .next-btn',
        },
        breakpoints: {
           1200: {
              slidesPerView: 'auto',
              spaceBetween: 40,
           },
           830: {
              slidesPerView: 'auto',
              spaceBetween: 10, // <- doesn't work
           }
        }
     });
  });
```

But it shows only one slide per view and ignores the space which is set in options.

[image]

How to set space between slides strictly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem with slidesPerView: 'auto' always showing only one slide. The solution for me was with CSS: [(codepen)](https://codepen.io/daltimus/pen/WNeMxyM)

```
.swiper-container{
  width: 100%;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
.slide-image {
  height: 400px;
  width: auto;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer It Worked, But My Slider Jumps From Last One In Loop To The First One. I added the configuration just as it was in your codepem project. can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `slidesPerView: 'auto'`, use this

```
breakpoints: {
      "@0.00": {
        slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      "@0.75": {
        slidesPerView: 2,
      },
      "@1.00": {
        slidesPerView: 3,
      },
      "@1.50": {
        slidesPerView: 4,
      },
```

Comment: What does this to? can you please explain?

Comment: @FabianS. it works like a media query for swiper

Comment: Okay, but what does the `@...` values refer to? Whats `@1.00` ?

Comment: @FabianS. These are ratios according to the doc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Vue and Tailwind.

I solved it by adding `slidesPerView:'auto'` property on the wrapper and CSS `width: fit-content;` on the slides.

```
<Swiper slides-per-view="auto" :space-between="10">
   <SwiperSlide class="w-fit">
     ...
   </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

Comment: I had the same problem (no Vue, just Tailwind). But I had to add the "important" CSS modifier to `w-fit`. So finally, on the items with class `swiper-slide`, I added an additional class `!w-fit` and it worked.